# Regular expression to find id from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, regex

I have some JavaScript code in string format. Target is such a string:

```
productPage.loadProductData("138674", "initial", "1");
```

How can I extract '138674'?

I'm using this line:

```
from re import search as re_search, sub as re_sub, compile as re_compile
print re_search(r'productPage.loadProductData("?P<pid>\d+","?P<x>\w+","?P<n>\d+");', open_link).groupdict()["pid"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python `(?P<name>regex)` is called a named capturing group. You forgot the opening and closing brace in the named capturing group. And also you need to escape `(` in your regular expression to match a literal `(` symbol.

```
>>> s = 'productPage.loadProductData("138674","initial","1");'
>>> print re.search(r'productPage.loadProductData\("(?P<pid>\d+)","(?P<x>\w+)","(?P<n>\d+)"\);', s).group("pid")
138674
```

OR

```
>>> print re.search(r'productPage.loadProductData\("(?P<pid>\d+)","(?P<x>\w+)","(?P<n>\d+)"\);', s).groupdict()["pid"]
138674
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the regular expression-based approach, you can solve it with a [`slimit` JavaScript parser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/slimit):

```
from slimit.ast import String
from slimit.parser import Parser
from slimit.visitors import nodevisitor

data = 'productPage.loadProductData("138674","initial","1");'

parser = Parser()
tree = parser.parse(data)
print next(node.value for node in nodevisitor.visit(tree) if isinstance(node, String))
```

This would output the first `String` node out of the JavaScript code in the `data` variable.

Comment: Every time i have another html with another data, so this is not a solution

Comment: i can use only Beautiful Soup and regexp

Comment: @goquartzquartz believe it or not, this is the solution to the question you've asked.

Comment: this is a solution I think, when You cant use hard coded values and 3d party libs 
print re.search(r'productPage.loadProductData\("(?P<pid>\d+)","(?P<x>\w+)","(?P<n>\d+)"\);', s).groupdict()["pid"]
138674

Comment: @goquartzquartz mhm, I've solved it with a regex - it's just that I've intentionally posted an alternative way to extract the value knowing that Avinash is already working on the regex-based approach. And I don't need credits for this - it's just an interesting challenge and fun exploring the other possible solutions to a problem :)

Comment: Thanks for new lib I have achieved!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do a regular expression on code, and don't use a specialized library to parse code - for example [Esprima](http://esprima.org/)?

Esprima parses code and outputs it in [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) format so you can now extract the name of the functions, the variables passed to it, etc.

Comment: i cant use any 3d party libs